# Celery with RabbitMq in django messages stays at Unacked status

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I'm using Celery v5.3.1 RabbitMq running in a container ( rabbitmq:3.8-management) and django V4.2.2

I like to send an email using Celery

so I added this `Celery.py` file

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")
app = Celery("app")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

I have this `settings.py` config file

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://bimauser:bimapass@localhost:5672//'
CELERY_BROKER_BACKEND = "db+sqlite:///celery.sqlite"
CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = "db+sqlite:///celery.sqlite"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "db+sqlite:///celery.sqlite"
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_WORKER_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
```

to send the email in a `receiveir.py` file I added this

```
@receiver(reset_password_signal)
def send_password_reset_email(sender, **kwargs):
    email = kwargs['email']
    reset_password_link = kwargs['reset_password_link']
    context = {
        'reset_password_link': reset_password_link,
    }
    message = render_to_string('user/reset_password_email.html', context)
    mail_subject = 'Password Reset'
    send_email_async.delay(mail_subject, message, email)
```

and here the code for `send_email_async` in `tasks.py` file

```
@shared_task(max_retries=3)
def send_email_async(mail_subject, message, email):
    # task = EmailService.send_email.delay(mail_subject, message, email)
    print("test2")
    print("test1")
    print("test5")
    base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(settings.__file__))
    file_path = os.path.join(base_dir, 'testfile.txt')

    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        file.write('This is a test file.')
    # task.get()
```

so first I was trying to send an email this does not work so I chaned to just write a file to see the result

I ofcourse run my container (rabbitmq)
I lunch celery worker
`python -m celery -A app worker -l debug`

and when I try to call the `send_password_reset_email()` in the `receiver.py` file

I see in the log of celery that he received the task and he make self.run

here the log

```
[2023-07-07 11:02:42,081: INFO/MainProcess] Task user.tasks.send_email_async[c04b8afa-3d19-4f22-b662-8c7156a8c89e] received
[2023-07-07 11:02:42,081: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply <function fast_trace_task at 0x0000029DD83B6200> (args:('user.tasks.send_email_async', 'c04b8afa-3d19-4f22-b662-8c7156a8c89e', {'lang': 'py', 'task': 'user.tasks.send_email_async', 'id': 'c04b8afa-3d19-4f22-b662-8c7156a8c89e', 'shadow': None, 'eta': None, 'expires': None, 'group': None, 'group_index': None, 'retries': 0, 'timelimit': [None, None], 'root_id': 'c04b8afa-3d19-4f22-b662-8c7156a8c89e', 'parent_id': None, 'argsrepr': "('Password Reset', '\nHi,\nPlease click on the link below to reset your password:\nhttp://127.0.0.1:8000//api/user/reset-password/MQ/bqys0i-ce51b3cfb73e0769d9f223b2cb38047f/\nIf you didn\\'t request this, please ignore this email.\nYour account is safe.\nBest,\nYour website team\n\n', 'admin@admin.com')", 'kwargsrepr': '{}', 'origin': 'gen20876@rdmbima_laptop', 'ignore_result': False, 'stamped_headers': None, 'stamps': {}, 'properties': {'content_type': 'application/json', 'content_encoding': 'utf-8', 'application_headers': {'lang': 'py', 'task': 'user.tasks.send_email_async', 'id': 'c04b8afa-3d19-4f22-b662-8c7156a8c89e', 'shadow': None,... kwargs:{})
[2023-07-07 11:02:42,196: DEBUG/MainProcess] Timer wake-up! Next ETA 0.8120000000053551 secs.
[2023-07-07 11:02:42,691: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 20
[2023-07-07 11:02:42,691: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 24
[2023-07-07 11:02:42,706: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 20
[2023-07-07 11:02:42,706: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 24
[2023-07-07 11:02:42,761: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 20
[2023-07-07 11:02:42,762: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 24
[2023-07-07 11:02:42,768: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 20
[2023-07-07 11:02:42,770: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 24
[2023-07-07 11:02:42,818: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 20
[2023-07-07 11:02:42,819: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 24
[2023-07-07 11:02:42,823: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 20
[2023-07-07 11:02:42,823: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 24
[2023-07-07 11:02:42,824: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 20
[2023-07-07 11:02:42,827: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 24
[2023-07-07 11:02:42,838: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 20
[2023-07-07 11:02:42,840: DEBUG/MainProcess] recreated blocker with handle 24
[2023-07-07 11:02:43,012: DEBUG/MainProcess] Timer wake-up! Next ETA 1.0 secs.
[2023-07-07 11:02:43,016: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-15] child process 29428 calling self.run()
```

I find in the RabbitMQ management interface that here is a new message but it stays at `Unacked status`

no email was sent (and when I tried to just write the file, no file was creating)

I find in the net that I should add this to run my worker

`python -m celery -A app worker -l info -E --pool=solo`

this solve my problem, but as I read that --pool solo is not recomanded for production

I tried to find a better way then using the single pool
but what ever option I put messages stay at unacked status